# Draw UIImage in a CALayer

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, calayer

Is it possible to draw an existing `png` image inside a `CALayer`? If not, how can I have the image as a sublayer of a `CALayer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, just set layer's `contents`:

```
layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageNamed"].CGImage;
```